# Why I can't see Viber Videos folder in Windows Explorer (on Huawei P9)

Tags: huawei, viber-messenger

When I connect my Huawei P9 to a PC and browse folders I can see viber/media folders on both Internal Storage and SD Card. In this folder I can see Viber Images and some dot folders, but no Viber Videos or User Images.

When I browse folders on the phone itself it shows these folders.

How can I see them in Windows Explorer?

Comment: Really not sure, see maybe those are hidden files? They shouldn't be but if they are, go to the view tab and select "show hidden files"

Comment: They are not hidden. I see a bunch of hidden folders like .ptt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that folder has some kind of system protection.

However, there is a way to see images and videos (at least on Huawei P8): Open Files app (Huawei's default file explorer) and go to /viber/media and rename it's child folders (Viber Images and Viber Videos) and you'll be able to see them in Windows 10 Explorer.